Javascript object properties access
I found one question regarding accessing object properties with using array literals and I was confused to understand how its working
const obj = {
  "1": "a",
  1: "b",
  [1]: "c",
  [2]: "k"
}
console.log(obj[1]) // c
console.log(obj[[1]]) //c


Can someone explain how this is working ?
I tried checking documentation but it wasn't much helpful to get accurate answer

The answers in the marked duplicate give the answer. If you want to see it in action print out obj with console.log(obj). You will notice that there is only one key for 1 and it's value is c.

object keys are always strings, so the first 1 key is a string, but the second one is overwriting it.
